# How do you mock up Throwable object?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I want to write Junit test for handling error method for my application and it looks like this

```
public void myHandlingError(Throwable t) {//content}
```

I want to mock up Throwable object but I could not find any example. 
Here is what I am thinking...

```
   public void myHandlingErrorTest(){
       Throwable t = new Exception();
       myClass.myHandlingError(t);
       .
       .
       .
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term **mock** somehow implies that you use a mocking framework such as EasyMock to create that object you are looking for. But for objects representing exceptions that is rarely necessary. You see, exceptions are typically created on "bad input".

What my tests typically do: drive some "bad" input into a class; and then expect that a certain exception is thrown. My test catches that exception, and retrieves one or more of the properties of that exception; for example its message (verified using asserts).

And, on the other hand: exceptions are something that you create using **new** within your production code (most of the time). Thus there are no easy ways to mock that anyway. And creating a factory for exceptions, and using dependency injection ... sounds like overkill. You see, the nice things about exceptions is: in most cases, code is about: "bad input that throws up". So you just provide bad input, and except the exception to be thrown in your test for further verification.

In your case, you are testing code that is actually receiving throwable/exceptions objects as parameters; here it is just fine to go with the approach you started with - create the object in your test and pass it to your "handler".

Answer (score 1):

To echo [GhostCat's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39340210/1426891), you shouldn't be using mocks for exceptions or throwables. This is for a few reasons:

- Exceptions are a type of *data object*: Rather than acting as a collaborator, exceptions carry a piece of data between collaborators. Data objects are often laborious to mock, with many `get` methods to stub (and even more so for mutable data objects, where `set` would need to be mocked with matching side effects). Because data objects typically have no dependencies and stable implementations, there are very few downsides to using the real classes in tests.
- [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) has some hard-to-simulate system-provided methods like `fillInStackTrace`. You shouldn't be in the business of simulating something like that.
- Throwable also has some impossible-to-mock `final` methods, like `addSuppressed` and `getSuppressed`. Because they're final, EasyMock and Mockito can't use dynamic proxies to override them, so to even try to mock those methods you'd have to use PowerMock or some other bytecode-rewriting mocking tool.
- There is a wide variety of existing, easy-to-instantiate, well-tested system Exceptions that you can create and pass in, including `IllegalArgumentException`, `NullPointerException`, and even `RuntimeException` itself.
- Throwable, Exception, and RuntimeException are very explicitly designed for subclassing, so if you do want to test with a custom subclass, you could very easily create a real nested Exception or Throwable subclass within your test.

Leave mocks for non-data objects where the *interaction* matters to your SUT or MUT's general contract, and use real objects or inputs for your throwables and exceptions.